# Creating Raw Graphic Elements (no Windows chrome)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, wpf, windows

I am new to Windows 7 programming and am trying to get a sense of what technologies or frameworks I should be using (I suppose within .NET) that will let me create graphical elements on the screen without any of the standard Windows UI chrome (resize handles, minimize/maximize, title bar etc.).

As a "hello world", I'd like to be able to create a 200x200 pixel box, red, with a slight transparency, that has the text "hello world" in it and maybe moves across the screen. That would be a great start into the kind of thing I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can set the `WindowStyle` to "`None`" and the `ResizeMode` to "`NoResize`" to remove the OS chrome from the window. To make the window translucent you need to set `AllowsTransparency` to "`True`" and set `Opacity` to a percent value of your choosing.

Here's a window with no chrome and an 80% opacity:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Opacity="0.8"
    Title="Test Window" Height="300" Width="300">
```

You can even create a brush and set that to the Window's `OpacityMask` property to make the window non-square.